# How event loop works for multiple tabs of browser and services in nodejs

Tags: javascript, event-loop

I am confused about how Callstack, CallbackQueue, and Eventloop work for multiple tabs.

Is the same Callstack, CallbackQueue, and Eventloop shared by multiple tabs of the browser or does it create a new instance of the whole thing every time a new tab is created?

Same question regarding multiple NodeJS services running on the same machine.
For example, if service A is running on port 8080 and service B is running on Port 8181. Will both services share Callstack, CallbackQueue, and Eventloop?

If they are shared then will service A affect performance of service B and same for Tab will Tab A affect performance of Tab B?

Comment: Every window or tab is independent, analogous to a process in an operating system.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar, one add on the question, then why do inactive tabs slow down. Like if there is a tab A that is running setInterval and then there is another tab B that goes Active leaving tab A inactive. Now setInterval of the tab A is not performing as well as it was when it was active.

Comment: Because the browser deliberately gives inactive tabs lower priority.

Comment: [This article](http://hassansin.github.io/shared-event-loop-among-same-origin-windows) has some experiments that suggest that same-origin tabs share an event loop, at least in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

`Every window or tab is independent, analogous to a process in an operating system. – Barmar`

The same goes for NodeJS processes. Each service is a separate process. Unless one process is using all your hardware resources or bandwidth, they have little to no impact on each others' performance.

Comment: ... assuming that you don't just create two HTTP servers in one NodeJS app, but that these services really are separate apps.

Comment: Tabs in a browser are not really independent no, the browser will have various helper processes, but not as much as you can have tabs. They will actually share single processes for various tabs.